# Communicating between 2 flask apps in docker containers

Tags: python, docker, flask

With 2 flask apps inside 2 separate containers, I thought it would be possible to run a `GET` request from one and return information from the second, but I get `[Errno 111] Connection refused`. With the following setup:

app1.py

```
@app.route('/get_message')
def get_message():
    message = requests.get('http://web2:5001/return_message')
    return message.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

app2.py

```
@app.route('/return_message')
def return_message():
    return 'the message'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web1:
    build: ./web1
    container_name: web1
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
  web2:
    build: ./web2
    container_name: web2
    ports: 
      - "5001:5001"
```

The endpoint for app1 works when going to http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_message, but flask returns:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='web2', port=5001): Max retries exceeded with url: /return_message (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb866642d30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Trying to assign a static IP address to the web2 container and using the IP in the `get` request doesn't work, neither does using `networks`, `link` or `depends_on` inside the `docker-compose` file. Also tried exposing different ports on both containers in different combinations but doesn't get the message between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that when you spin your apps they both run on port `5000` but in different containers so try changing your `app1.py` to :

```
@app.route('/get_message')
def get_message():
    message = requests.get('http://web2:5000/return_message')
    return message.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And also change ports in docker-compose for `web2` :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web1:
    build: ./web1
    container_name: web1
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
  web2:
    build: ./web2
    container_name: web2
    ports: 
      - "5001:5000"
```

However changing ports in docker-compose is not necessary if you do not want to acces `web2` from host - keep in mind that here I map port 5001 of your host to port 5000 of web2 container and both your containers expose app on port 5000.

Remember that these are seperate containers so like seperate environments. And also keep in mind that `EXPOSE` is only for documenting that you expose some service at this port - it does not make your app in the container run on this port.

Comment: I'd already tried this and unfortunately it gave the same result.

Comment: Are you sure you have tried exactly same configuration? And you have reloaded all your containers and checked it?

Comment: I just changed the configuration now to this and it still gives me the connection refusal, I'll check I'm not overriding something somewhere else but I don't think so.

Comment: Can you also try changing `host` in `app2.py` to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Well, that didn't work either but I realised I had only `app.run()` in `web2.py` so I tried with `0.0.0.0` and it works. Thanks very much.